# Compile fla to swf with actionscripts

Tags: adobe, flash, fla

I tried to compile `*.fla` and `*.ac` to `*.swf`, but just the `*.fla` file is compiled not ActionScripts `*.ac`.

Im using Adobe Flash CS6.

How can i Compile the file as a Perfect Swf File?

Comment: Do you mean `.as` or `.asc` file ? And how do you know if it wasn't compiled within your swf ?

Comment: my original swf size is 990 KB        after compiling: 220 KB